# Changing the order of integration $\int_1^\infty \int_{a/x^2}^\infty f(x,y) dy dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been given an integration to solve which looks like the following
$$\int_1^\infty \int_{a/x^2}^\infty f(x,y) dy dx$$

I want to change the order of integration from $dy dx$ to $dx dy$.

I have got an answer as
$$\int_0^\infty \int_{\sqrt{a/y}}^\infty f(x,y) dx dy$$

Do not know if it is correct or not.
Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help your question if you include the steps you used to get your answer. That would show effort on your part, without which questions get closed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Cavalieri's principle
$$ \begin{split} \int_1^\infty \int_{a/x^2}^\infty f(x,y) dy dx &= \int_1^\infty \int_{0}^\infty f(x,y)1_{y\ge a/x^2} dy dx\\
&=  \int_{0}^\infty \int_1^\infty f(x,y)1_{y\ge a/x^2} dx dy\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_1^\infty f(x,y)1_{x\ge \sqrt{a/y}} dx dy\\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{\max\big(1,\sqrt{a/y}\big)}^\infty f(x,y) dx dy
\end{split} $$

N.B. assuming $a\ge 0$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have two small confusions. I don't understand why did you put the lower limit as $\max(1,\sqrt{a/y})$. Also is $1_{y\geq a/x^2} a step function?

Comment: $x$ has to satisfy both $x\ge \sqrt{a/y}$ and $x\ge 1$, i.e. $x \ge \max(1,\sqrt{a/y})$.

Comment: $1_{P(x)}$ is a notation for the indicator function : takes the value $1$ if $P(x)$ is true, $0$ otherwise.